# Deleting Windows Partition + Installing Ubuntu = Please Help!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I installed Linux Mint about 2 years ago because my Windows side failed to boot. With Linux I was able to access the files I needed on the Windows side immediately, and go about my day (I did this in a hurry overnight to finish a paper).

I now have Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Windows installed on my Lenovo Ideapad U260

I tried to run a Lenovo One Key Recovery to save my Windows side last night, but all it did was wipe that side out and remove the option to boot into Linux, Ubuntu, Windows, and all their safety editions. Now I can only boot with a shitty live Mint CD or DriveDroid Ubuntu 14.04 (the only options I have). My Linux OS's are still there, but I can't boot into them. I don't care if they disappear, I backed everything up, but they do not have enough space to run well.

I opened GParted and want to remove my Windows partition since I haven't used it in 2 years - is this a bad idea? I cannot resize it, and that may be related to the following:

I did a check & repair with GParted on my Windows partition from the Ubuntu DriveDroid live that I have in now and it says:

> Check and repair file system (ntfs) on /dev/sda2  00:00:43    ( ERROR
>   )
>          calibrate /dev/sda2  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
>          path: /dev/sda2 start: 411648 end: 533389311 size: 532977664 (254.14 GiB) check file system on /dev/sda2 for errors and (if
>   possible) fix them  00:00:43    ( ERROR )
>          ntfsresize -i -f -v /dev/sda2
>          ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g) Device name : /dev/sda2 NTFS volume version: 3.1 Cluster size : 4096 bytes Current volume
>   size: 272884560384 bytes (272885 MB) Current device size: 272884563968
>   bytes (272885 MB) Checking for bad sectors ... Checking filesystem
>   consistency ... ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output
>   error Failed to read of MFT, mft=41652 count=1 br=-1: Input/output
>   error ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed
>   to read of MFT, mft=41653 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
>   ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to
>   read of MFT, mft=41654 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
>   ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to
>   read of MFT, mft=41655 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
>   ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to
>   read of MFT, mft=56880 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
>   ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to
>   read of MFT, mft=56881 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
>   ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to
>   read of MFT, mft=56882 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
>   ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to
>   read of MFT, mft=56883 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error Cluster
>   2946578 is referenced multiple times! Cluster 2946579 is referenced
>   multiple times! Cluster 2946580 is referenced multiple times! Cluster
>   2946581 is referenced multiple times! Cluster 2946582 is referenced
>   multiple times! Cluster 2946583 is referenced multiple times! Cluster
>   2946584 is referenced multiple times! Cluster 2946585 is referenced
>   multiple times! Cluster 2946586 is referenced multiple times! Cluster
>   2946587 is referenced multiple times! Cluster 2946588 is referenced
>   multiple times! Cluster 2946589 is referenced multiple times!
>   100.00 percent completed ERROR: Filesystem check failed! ERROR: 12 clusters are referenced multiple times. NTFS is inconsistent. Run
>   chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE! The usage of the /f
>   parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was and will be made to
>   NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.

I don't know what the hell any of that means.

I have backed up everything.

If I delete my Windows partition, can I still boot ubuntu from a live usb (DriveDroid) and install it into the newly unallocated space?

Answer (score 1):

> If I delete my Windows partition, can I still boot ubuntu from a live usb (DriveDroid) and install it into the newly unallocated space?

Yes. It looks like the Windows partition is corrupted. This will not prevent you from booting from a live usb. Formatting the partition should allow you to safely install a version of ubuntu assuming the hard drive itself is not damaged.

Comment: should I format my windows side or delete the partition? What's the difference?

Comment: Deleting the partition will leave it as unallocated space on the hard drive, which cannot be used. You should format it instead, I suggest selecting EXT4 as the file system.

Comment: thanks man! okay, just to confirm before I do this: while I am in ubuntu right now, I can use GParted to format the 254.14 Gb ntfs file system. Then can I just install Ubuntu from this live disk? Or should I reboot?

Will it automatically take up that 250G or will I manually need to assign it?

Comment: and what do you mean select EXT4 as the file system? A lot of the language is foreign to me still

Comment: When you right click the partition and select "format to..." you will need to select which file system you would like to format it to. EXT4 is the one you want. You may need to unmount the partition to format it, and you'll need to re-mount it to install Ubuntu on to it. It shouldn't be necessary to restart. During the installation process you will be asked where you want to install Ubuntu, just select that partition and it should automatically fill it.

Comment: If Ubuntu and Mint are still there and One key deleted grub, all you need to do is reinstall grub to get access to them. On the other hand, if you don't care if your OS's disappear, simply install Ubuntu on the entire disk, the installer will get rid of all the partitions and create a new one for Ubuntu + a Swap partition.

Comment: ^ this is good advice. To repair grub you can use boot-repair. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I'm gonna look this up also, but what should the mount point be? options include /boot, /var, /usr/local, /home, /temp, etc. I chose "Use As" to be Ext4. I decided to not delete or touch my other Linux OS till I'm settled in the new Ubuntu OS in this partition I'm making now